# Rails association: Invalid type of save method in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I want use rails for server and post data by `http` and `post` method and then save data to database. For this, I have 2 models and controllers: `bolouk` and 'radif'.
I have below association:

`models/bolouk.rb`:

```
class Bolouk < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :radifs, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

`models/radif.rb`:

```
class Radif < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bolouk
end
```

I can create new `bolouk`, but when I want create new `radif`, I send all method that I need for create new radif in database(like `bolouk_id` and radif parameters), and I recieve this data in rails server and `create action`, but when I want create new method, I get `500 Internal Error`.

`controller/api/v1/radifs_controller.rb`:

```
class Api::V1::RadifsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def create
    @radif = Radif.create(radif_params)
    if @radif.valid?
      puts "if"
      respond_with @radif, :location => api_bolouk_radifs_path
    else
      puts "else"
      respond_with @radif.errors, :location => api_bolouks_radifs_path
    end
  end
  private
  def radif_params
    params.require(:radif).permit(:bolouk_id, :describe, :price)
  end
end
```

I put some log in create action, I define controller detect `@radif` is `invalid` and doesn't save `@radif` in database. I put server log in below:

```
Started POST "/api/bolouks/23/radifs?describe=110&price=128" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-03 16:05:37 +0430
Processing by Api::V1::RadifsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"bolouk_id"=>"23", "describe"=>"110", "price"=>"128", "radif"=>{"bolouk_id"=>"23"}}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 7  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
else
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

I send data from angularjs, I have below code:
`newradif.html`:

```
<form ng-submit="saveRadif()" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-repeat="err in errors">{{err}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="radifdescribe" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><span>Describe:</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input ng-model='modalRadif.describe' class="form-control" id="radifdescribe" placeholder="describe">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="radifprice" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><span>Price</span></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input ng-model="modalRadif.price" class="form-control" id="radifprice" placeholder="price">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and in angularjs controller:

```
    $scope.saveRadif = function(){
            Radifs.create($scope.modalRadif, {bolouk_id: $scope.saveBolouk.id}).$promise.then(function(data){
                $scope.radifs = Radifs.index({bolouk_id: $scope.saveBolouk.id});
    //            $scope.saveRadif = data;
            })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err.data);

                })
        }
app.factory('Radifs', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/bolouks/:bolouk_id/radifs', {bolouk_id: '@bolouk_id'}, {
        index: { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    });
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your describe and price are outside of radif hash in parameters. Can you show your form? Also you need to call save method instead of create.

Comment: I add form to question.

Comment: @Mandeep Your guide is very useful. I check form and edit type of data sending.

Answer (score 0):

In your model classes, you have defined a has_many and belongs_to association between Bolouk and Radif models. So you could create a new Radif object that belongs to a Bolouk object in the following way.

```
def create
  @bolouk = Bolouk.find(params[:bolouk_id])
  @radif = @bolouk.radifs.build(radif_params)
  if @radif.save
    respond_with @radif, :location => api_bolouk_radifs_path
  else
    respond_with @radif.errors, :location => api_bolouk_radifs_path
  end    
end
```

Comment: I add this code to `radifs_controller`, but data is doesn't save to database again.

Comment: I add log in controller, `@radif` doesn't save and run `else` statement.

Comment: Is there any diffrent between `@radif.save` and `@radif.save!`? When I use `@radif.save!` I get this error: `"Validation failed: Describe can't be blank, Price can't be blank"`.

Comment: In activerecord, usually methods ending with ! raise an exception on failure. It is not a good idea to use save! unless you have a good reason for it. Use @radif.save and it will return true if successful. About the error, looks like there are some validations in place for describe and price attributes. I would strongly recommend you to read the following guides thoroughly..
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html